# SQL group by (count,sum)

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello i need help abou SQL a have this table

[image: My table]

and i need this result.

[image: Result waned]

thanks for your attention and your answers.

```
select 
to_char(r.date,'yyyy') YEAR,
sum(1),
sum(r.cafe) cafe,
sum(r.drink) drink,
sum(r.tea) tea
from ucet a
join  drinks r on a.IDT=r.IDT
join feat ce on a.IDT=ce.IDT
join dance c on a.ID= c.ID

group by to_char(r.date,'yyyy')
```

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. Additionally, please post your data as formatted text, instead of pictures.

Comment: It is clear what you need. But is it not clear what issue you are facing in writing query.

Comment: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/sql-tutorial/sql-get-started.php here a website to start practicing your sql.

Comment: This is very basic stuff, with an abundance of material available on the web - please do some research and answer your own question.

Comment: i have problem about code , because i can not use sum for number , and i do not know what i can use so result was right .

Comment: i use PLSQL developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sum and group by as below:

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT YEAR(r.date) year,
 COUNT(DISTINCT(number)) number,
 SUM(r.cafe) cafe,
 SUM(r.drink) drink,
 SUM(r.tea) tea
FROM drinks r
JOIN ucet a on a.IDT = r.IDT
GROUP BY YEAR(r.date)
```

Please also bear in mind that date is a reserved word for a datatype in many RDBMS systems, as such I would suggest naming your columns as something more appropriate, avoiding reserved words.

Comment: i have to use function left ? thanks for your answer

Comment: apologies just noticed you are using plsql - I will review my answer

Comment: its not working how i want. because . the column number tell that how many times is number in year . number 11111 is 1 time in 2015 and 1 time in 2016 ...... number 22222 is 1 time in 2015 and 1 time in 2016 . so together in 2015 is 2 number and 2016 is 2 number

Comment: @dado I dont know what data you have in your joined tables and how these relate in the query. It does appear that you are only taking data from the drinks table or (r) if this is correct then you can simply remove the join to the ucet table, and that will get you to the groupings that you require. I suspect your ucet table is causing the rows to duplicate. I have updated the script above to only use the drinks table.

Comment: so i use table with column 'number' because it is 'ID_of_person' and i want to say that in 2016 came to my bar two people and in 2015 too two people

Comment: @dado - I think I follow, although it would have been easier if you had provided your table examples in addition to the required output. However I have updated the script based on your requirements could you please review the change and mark the answer as appropriate.

Comment: i use PL SQL developer and when i use function YEAR do not work it

Comment: i used to_char insted of YEAR  and it work thanks for your attention